# He was known for a great pioneer

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He was known for a great pioneer.

Does the sentence look idiomatic?

I think 'as' instead for is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. "For" in that setting is not only non-idiomatic, it's actually wrong.

**As** relates to the person. It is equivalent to "to be". These sentences are the same:

1. He was known as a great pioneer.
2. He was known to be a great pioneer.

**For** relates to the qualities or activities of the person. For example:

3. He was known as a great pioneer.
4. He was known for his great pioneering deeds.
5. She was known as a kind-hearted woman.
6. She was known for her kind heart, and for all the work she did at the local community hall.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it should be:

> He was known **as** a great pioneer.

Or:

> He was known **for being** a great pioneer.